# From an array of objects with dates and time, I need to filter the next 24 hours

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is part of a booking system I've been trying to develop. At the moment it works in a way that it shows only the next day available slots, by creating a new day and filtering the array below with todaysDate+1. If the result is 0, (no slots or none available) it increases 1 day an shows the slot for the day after tomorrow, and so on.

Now, I need a way to filter from the array below the slots available within the next day 24 hours from the time I open the system.

If it is 10am, I should show the slots available from tomorrow 10am till the day after tomorrow 10am. (24 hours range starting from next day)

Taking as an example the array below, let's assume that today is 2019-07-08 and it is 11:30:00, I should then be able to filter this array and show only the available slots from 2019-07-09, 9:30:00 until 2019-07-10, 11:30:00.

```
var dataDB = [
    {ID: "404",  date: "2019-07-08", time_slot: "09:30:00", available: "1"},
    {ID: "405",  date: "2019-07-08", time_slot: "10:00:00", available: "1"},
    {ID: "406",  date: "2019-07-08", time_slot: "10:30:00", available: "1"},
    {ID: "407",  date: "2019-07-08", time_slot: "11:00:00", available: "1"},
    {ID: "408",  date: "2019-07-08", time_slot: "11:30:00", available: "1"},
    {ID: "414",  date: "2019-07-09", time_slot: "09:30:00", available: "1"},
    {ID: "415",  date: "2019-07-09", time_slot: "10:00:00", available: "1"},
    {ID: "416",  date: "2019-07-09", time_slot: "10:30:00", available: "1"},
    {ID: "417",  date: "2019-07-09", time_slot: "11:00:00", available: "1"},
    {ID: "418",  date: "2019-07-09", time_slot: "11:30:00", available: "1"},
    {ID: "424",  date: "2019-07-10", time_slot: "09:30:00", available: "1"},
    {ID: "425",  date: "2019-07-10", time_slot: "10:00:00", available: "1"},
    {ID: "426",  date: "2019-07-10", time_slot: "10:30:00", available: "1"},
    {ID: "427",  date: "2019-07-10", time_slot: "11:00:00", available: "0"},
    {ID: "432",  date: "2019-07-10", time_slot: "14:15:00", available: "1"},
    {ID: "433",  date: "2019-07-10", time_slot: "14:45:00", available: "1"},
    {ID: "434",  date: "2019-07-11", time_slot: "09:30:00", available: "1"},
    {ID: "435",  date: "2019-07-11", time_slot: "10:00:00", available: "1"},
    {ID: "438",  date: "2019-07-11", time_slot: "11:30:00", available: "1"},
    {ID: "439",  date: "2019-07-11", time_slot: "12:00:00", available: "1"}
]
```

Comment: where is your specific problem? do you have some code? please add the wanted result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of the date/time in the data isn't great but this would work:

```
var dataDB = [
{ID: "404",  date: "2019-07-08", time_slot: "09:30:00", available: "1"},
{ID: "405",  date: "2019-07-08", time_slot: "10:00:00", available: "1"},
{ID: "406",  date: "2019-07-08", time_slot: "10:30:00", available: "1"},
{ID: "407",  date: "2019-07-08", time_slot: "11:00:00", available: "1"},
{ID: "408",  date: "2019-07-08", time_slot: "11:30:00", available: "1"},
{ID: "414",  date: "2019-07-09", time_slot: "09:30:00", available: "1"},
{ID: "415",  date: "2019-07-09", time_slot: "10:00:00", available: "1"},
{ID: "416",  date: "2019-07-09", time_slot: "10:30:00", available: "1"},
{ID: "417",  date: "2019-07-09", time_slot: "11:00:00", available: "1"},
{ID: "418",  date: "2019-07-09", time_slot: "11:30:00", available: "1"},
{ID: "424",  date: "2019-07-10", time_slot: "09:30:00", available: "1"},
{ID: "425",  date: "2019-07-10", time_slot: "10:00:00", available: "1"},
{ID: "426",  date: "2019-07-10", time_slot: "10:30:00", available: "1"},
{ID: "427",  date: "2019-07-10", time_slot: "11:00:00", available: "0"},
{ID: "432",  date: "2019-07-10", time_slot: "14:15:00", available: "1"},
{ID: "433",  date: "2019-07-10", time_slot: "14:45:00", available: "1"},
{ID: "434",  date: "2019-07-11", time_slot: "09:30:00", available: "1"},
{ID: "435",  date: "2019-07-11", time_slot: "10:00:00", available: "1"},
{ID: "438",  date: "2019-07-11", time_slot: "11:30:00", available: "1"},
{ID: "439",  date: "2019-07-11", time_slot: "12:00:00", available: "1"}
]

var today = new Date();
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);

var results = dataDB.filter(row => (new Date(String.prototype.concat(row.date, "T", String.prototype.concat(row.time_slot)))) >= today && (new Date(String.prototype.concat(row.date, "T", String.prototype.concat(row.time_slot)))) <= tomorrow));
```

Just note that the above will use local time to identify when now ('today') and 24 hours from now ('tomorrow') are, so if the time zones don't match up with the data you could get weird results. You can use UTC date methods, however, if that's an issue.

Comment: Thanks, this is working great. Just learned that I can use a date value and a time value and put them together this way.